# Configuring Jenkins SSH options to slave nodes

Tags: jenkins, ssh, tty

I am running Jenkins on Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty Tahr) with slave nodes via SSH. We're able to communicate with the nodes to run most commands, but when a command requires a tty input, we get the classic

```
the input device is not a TTY
```

error. In our case, it's a `docker exec -it` command.

So I'm searching through loads of information about Jenkins, trying to figure out how to configure the connection to the slave node to enable the `-t` option to force tty instances, and I'm coming up empty. How do we make this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you cannot give `-t` to the ssh that Jenkins fires up (which makes sense, as Jenkins is inherently detached). From [the documentation](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SSH+Slaves+plugin):

> When the SSH slaves plugin connects to a slave, it does not run an interactive shell. Instead it does the equivalent of your running "ssh slavehost command..." a few times...

However, you can defeat this in your build scripts by...

- looping back to yourself: `ssh -t localhost command`
- using a local [PTY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoterminal) generator: `script --return -c "command" /dev/null`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the "-t" option! The `script` seems to lose the output of the command. Am I right?